# HTTP Request using Sockets in C

Tags: c, sockets, http

SO. I'm trying to make a C application that retrieves the .html file from a server, for example [www.example.com](http://example.com). For this I'm using Sockets and `connect` `send` and `recv` methods. My implementation looks like this:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    //Stream sockets and rcv()
    
    struct addrinfo hints, *res;
    int sockfd;
    
    char buf[2056];
    int byte_count;
    
    //get host info, make socket and connect it
    memset(&hints, 0,sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family=AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    getaddrinfo("www.example.com","80", &hints, &res);
    sockfd = socket(res->ai_family,res->ai_socktype,res->ai_protocol);
    printf("Connecting...\n");
    connect(sockfd,res->ai_addr,res->ai_addrlen);
    printf("Connected!\n");
    char *header = "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1\nHost: www.example.com\n";
    send(sockfd,header,sizeof header,0);
    printf("GET Sent...\n");
    //all right ! now that we're connected, we can receive some data!
    byte_count = recv(sockfd,buf,sizeof buf,0);
    printf("recv()'d %d bytes of data in buf\n",byte_count);
    printf("%s",buf);
    return 0;
}
```

But the thing is that it gets stuck at the `recv` for some seconds, then the buffer `buf` is filled with this:

```
HTTP/1.0 408 Request Timeout
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 431
Connection: close
Date: Tue, 26 May 2015 23:08:46 GMT
Server: ECSF (fll/0781)

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>408 - Request Timeout</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>408 - Request Timeout</h1>
        <div>Server timeout waiting for the HTTP request from the client.</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Apparently the server never gets my GET string or it might be mal-formed, what is the correct way to go around with this?

I already downloaded libcurl and even got the http response in a file (which is great so I can process it later) but I was eager to do it all by hand.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Question has been answered already, but make sure you close the connection at the end of your program using close(sockfd).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The reason the server is timing out is because you are not sending a valid request.  Like Halim pointed out, your request data incomplete, you are using `LF` instead of `CRLF` for the line breaks, and missing the final line break to end the request header.

But, even after fixing that, your code is STILL not sending the request correctly.  This is because you are using a `char*` to point at your request data, and then passing `sizeof(char*)` as the data length to `send()`.  So you are only sending 4 bytes (`"GET "`) or 8 bytes (`"GET /ind"`), depending on whether you are compiling a 32bit or 64bit executable.  You need to use `strlen()` instead of `sizeof()`:

```
char *header = "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.example.com\r\n\r\n";
send(sockfd,header,strlen(header),0);
```

Once you get that part working, your `recv()` logic is not parsing the server's response at all, which I assume is you simply not having gotten that far yet.  But more importantly, the data being received is not null-terminated, but your call to `printf()` after `recv()` assumes that it is.  You need to fix that as well, either like this:

```
byte_count = recv(sockfd,buf,sizeof(buf)-1,0); // <-- -1 to leave room for a null terminator
buf[byte_count] = 0; // <-- add the null terminator
printf("recv()'d %d bytes of data in buf\n",byte_count);
printf("%s",buf);
```

Or, like this:

```
byte_count = recv(sockfd,buf,sizeof(buf),0);
printf("recv()'d %d bytes of data in buf\n",byte_count);
printf("%.*s",byte_count,buf); // <-- give printf() the actual data size
```

And, of course, none of your code has any error handling in it at all.  You really need to do that.

Comment: I really get confused with the use of sizeof and strlen, I don't really know when should I use which; last time it happened to me with a socket configuration. This solved my problem, and yes, I will handle errors lately. Thanks.

Comment: `sizeof()` returns the byte size of whatever you pass to it.  You are passing it a pointer, so you get back the **size of the pointer itself** (4 bytes for 32bit, 8 bytes for 64bit), *NOT* the size of the data being pointed at!  On the other hand, when you pass a static array to `sizeof()`, you get the size of the full array.

Comment: I know this is old, but would appreciate if you put in a comment that explains that byte_count also refers to the last character position in the `char*`. Just for clarity.

Answer (score 5):

Each header must end with a `\r\n` instead of `\n`. And there is an additional `\r\n` to add at the end of the request :

```
GET /index.html HTTP/1.1\r\n
Host: www.example.com\r\n
\r\n
```

Comment: And then while you are at it, don't write HTTP code manually, use a third-party library, like CURL.

Comment: I'm still getting the same response from the server, even after changing what my message should look like with HTTP 1.0.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I already made a code using libcurl.h and it works great, but I wanted to know (and I think I should be able to) if I can make it manually. :)